# Modularity value outside of 0 to 1 using cluster spinglass for Community Detection in R

Tags: r, modularity, network-analysis

I am trying to run a community detection analysis for my dissertation using weighted edge-weights (i.e., polychoric correlations). I am using the `Spinglass` cluster analysis to detect communities. For some reason, my modularity (Q) values do not fall within the expected 0 to 1 range (based on the literature I have read on this). Can someone advise me as to why this may be happening and how I can correct it? Thank you very much!

```
#TESTING FOR COMMUNITIES
#create matrix table 
TeachAggDatagraph <- getWmat(TeachAggDataplot)
#convert matrix table to  qgraph graph
qgTeachA <- qgraph(TeachAggDatagraph)
#convert to igraph
graphTAD<- as.igraph(qgTeachA, attributes = TRUE) 
#Community detection for teacher aggression data
cluster_spinglass(graphTAD)
```

Output I receive:

```
IGRAPH clustering spinglass, groups: 2, mod: -7.5
        + groups:

        $"1"
       [1] 1 2 3
      
       $"2"
        [1] 4 5 6
```

As you can see my modularity value is equal to -7.5

Comment: I've got the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

As it is explained in the (unpublished) book [Statistical Network Analysis with igraph - Harvard University](https://sites.fas.harvard.edu/%7Eairoldi/pub/books/BookDraft-CsardiNepuszAiroldi2016.pdf) authored by igraph's author

> A clustering with zero modularity has exactly as many edges within
> clusters as we would expect in a graph that was generated by the null
> model, positive modularity scores represent good clusterings and
> negative scores represent bad ones where there are less edges in
> clusters than what we would expect in a randomly generated graph.

Or in Newman, M. (2010). Networks: An Introduction. 1st ed. Oxford University Press

> This quantity Q is called the modularity [239,250] and is a measure of
> the extent to which like is connected to like in a network. It is
> strictly less than 1, takes positive values if there are more edges
> between vertices of the same type than we would expect by chance, and
> negative ones if there are less.